# How to check GPS is active or inactive Ipad pragmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How to check where the GPS is active or Inactive means [Turn on or Turn off] for the ipad.

In pragmatically.  Is there any way to get status of GPS of Ipad.

Please help with this query.

@thanks In advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus` method of `CLLocationManager` class. This method will return `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` if gps is turned off or user denied to use location services for your application.

More info about this method - [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus)